# My timer is going up like this: +1 +2 +3 +4 (1,3,6,10,15)

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a timer for a CPS calculator but am having a problem (Using tkinker)

The seconds is going up by +1 +2 +3 +4 +5 +6 instead of +1 +1 +1 +1 +1
(It looks like 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21)

```
def add_second():
    global seconds
    seconds += 1


def update_time():
    add_second()
    time.configure(text=time.cget('text') + seconds)
    window.after(1000, update_time)
```

Could I please have some help as I can't see what is wrong ):

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def add_second():
    global seconds
    seconds += 1


def update_time():
    add_second()
    time.configure(text=str(seconds))
    window.after(1000, update_time)
```

No need to add the previous time each time with time.cget('text').

Comment: Thanks @whackamadoodle300! (Nice name)! That fixed it. Wish I asked sooner. : )